# Reading Google Bigquery data into dataframe

Tags: pandas, google-bigquery

I followed the instructions for read_gbq and it seems to work fine for the most part until the point when I assign it to a dataframe -

```
df_gbq=gbq.read_gbq('SELECT id FROM <bigquery tablename> LIMIT 10',project_id=project_id)
```

Instead of creating a data frame, it displays the following message:

> Your browser has been opened to visit:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fbigquery&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&response_type=code&client_id=495642085510-k0tmvj2m941jhre2nbqka17vqpjfddtd.apps.googleusercontent.com&access_type=offline
```

If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this
application with the command-line parameter

--noauth_local_webserver

I think it's trying to download the file instead of assigning it to a dataframe. How can I avoid this?

When I click the url, I am prompted to grant permission to :

pandas GBQ

after I allow pandas GBQ to manage the data, it tries to open a page on localhost:8080

this port is blocked by the sears firewall hence nothing is displayed.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to use `private_key` parameter as it's described [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#google-bigquery-experimental)

Comment: Thanks @MaxU. I saved the json file in google storage. when I run it I still get an exception -  "InvalidPrivateKeyFormat: Private key is missing or invalid. It should be service account private key JSON (file path or string contents) with at least two keys: 'client_email' and 'private_key'." I am not sure if it is a good idea to re-create the private key.